# How can Bash run a C program just compiled with gcc?

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

How do I execute/run c files (in the bash script) after I compile them within a bash script?

For example I use:

```
for i in `ls *.c`
do
  gcc $i -o "${i%.c}"
  //execute compiled i.c file here
done
```

Comment: First of all: [Bash pitfall number 1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29). Second: [proper quoting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618). Then your actual problem. :)

Answer (score 3):

Just execute the resultant executable in the normal way:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in *.c
do
  gcc -Wall -Wextra "$i" -o "${i%.c}"  &&  "./${i%.c}"
done
```

N.B. not parsing `ls` output, quoting arguments, improved compiler warnings, and using `&&` to execute only if compilation succeeded.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I solved it by making a STR set to pwd, redefined str to append "/${i%.c}" to end of it so that ultimately it would execute each file from having the full path of the file